# Insertion of node in a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, nodes

My university professor gave us the following code but i feel like the 3rd row from the bottom should be

```
temp -> next = curr -> next -> next
```

If I am mistaken why is it correct ?

!!Note, the new node should be placed in the middle of the linked list and not in an edge!!

```
void insert_list (struct node *head, int pos) {
    int k;
    struct node *temp, *curr;
    curr = ihead;
    for (k=1; k<pos; k++)
       curr = curr -> next;
    temp = (struct node *) malloc (sizeof (struct node));
    temp -> next = NULL;
    gets (temp -> student);
    scanf ("%d", &temp -> am);
    temp -> next = curr -> next;
    curr -> next = temp;
}
```

Comment: Side note: this code has some issues. What happens if `head == NULL` or if `pos` > the length of the list? Also, there seems to be a typo: `head` and `ihead`? Other issues that might popup: if `malloc` returns `NULL`, or `scanf` fails. And then there's `gets()`: [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036)

Comment: @JohnnyMopp we just started learning about linked lists, thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the elements `A B C D` and you insert X between B and C, then:

In the beginning:

- B would be `curr`
- C would be `curr->next`
- D would be `curr->next->next`

After your function:

- B would still be `curr`
- X would be `curr->next` and `temp`
- C would be `temp->next` and `curr->next->next`
- D would be `temp->next->next` and `curr->next->next->next`

so as to have the linked list: `A B X C D`.

If you used `curr->next->next`, `X->next` would point to D and you would lose C in the process.

Comment: oh I can see what you are talking about. Thanks for the help, I am new to this!

Comment: No worries, you're welcome. If that answered your question, please consider marking the answer as accepted.

Comment: Of course I will!